# https with WCF error: "Could not find base address that matches scheme https"

Tags: wcf, https

I go to https://mywebsite/MyApp/Myservice.svc and get the following error:

(The link works if I use http:// )

"*The service '/MyApp/MyService.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: Could not find a base address that matches scheme https for the endpoint with binding BasicHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http]..*"

**EDIT:** So if I change `address=""` to `address="https:// ..."` then I get this error instead:

"*Error: The protocol 'https' is not supported..... The ChannelDispatcher at 'https://.../Annotation.svc' with contract(s) '"Annotation"' is unable to open its IChannelListener.*"

Here's what my `Web.Config` looks like:

```
<services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="AnnotationWCF.AnnotationBehavior"
              name="AnnotationWCF.Annotation">
              <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_Annotation"
                      contract="AnnotationWCF.Annotation" />
              <endpoint address="" 
                  binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SecureTransport"
                  contract="AnnotationWCF.Annotation" />
              <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
```

```
<bindings>
<basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_Annotation" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
            maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
            maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
    </binding>
    <binding name="SecureTransport" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
            maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
        <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
        </security>
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
            maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
    </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It turned out that my problem was that I was using a load balancer to handle the SSL, which then sent it over http to the actual server, which then complained.

Description of a fix is here: http://blog.hackedbrain.com/2006/09/26/how-to-ssl-passthrough-with-wcf-or-transportwithmessagecredential-over-plain-http/

Edit: I fixed my problem, which was slightly different, after talking to microsoft support.

My silverlight app had its endpoint address in code going over https to the load balancer.  The load balancer then changed the endpoint address to http and to point to the actual server that it was going to. So on each server's web config I added a listenUri for the endpoint that was http instead of https

```
<endpoint address="" listenUri="http://[LOAD_BALANCER_ADDRESS]" ... />
```

Comment: The link -> http://blog.hackedbrain.com/archive/2006/09/26/5281.aspx is not working.

Comment: Use link-> http://blog.hackedbrain.com/2006/09/26/how-to-ssl-passthrough-with-wcf-or-transportwithmessagecredential-over-plain-http/

Answer (score 31):

I had this exact same problem.  Except my solution was to add an "s" to the binding value.

**Old:** 
binding="mexHttpBinding"

**New:**
binding="mexHttpsBinding"

**web.config snippet:**

```
<services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="LIMS.UI.Web.WCFServices.Accessioning.QuickDataEntryService">
        <endpoint behaviorConfiguration="AspNetAjaxBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webBinding" 
            contract="LIMS.UI.Web.WCFServices.Accessioning.QuickDataEntryService" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    </service>
```

Answer (score 9):

Make sure SSL is enabled for your server!

I got this error when trying to use a HTTPS configuration file on my local box which doesn't have that certificate. I was trying to do local testing - by converting some of the bindings from HTTPS to HTTP. I thought it would be easier to do this than try to install a self signed certificate for local testing.

Turned out I was getting this error becasue **I didn't have SSL enabled** on my local IIS even though I wasn't intending on actually using it.

There was something in the configuration for HTTPS. Creating  a self signed cert in IIS7 allowed HTTP to then work :-)

Comment: I found that it was enough to make sure IIS (6.0) was listening on port 443 (right-click Default Web Site, Properties, SSL port, restart). I didn't go as far as creating a certificate.

Comment: I found the above comment from @rory-macleod to be very helpful.  When running locally, make sure to enable SSL by right-clicking on the project within Visual Studio and then setting "SSL Enabled" to "true" within the Project Properties panel.  Then, you will be prompted to install the self-signed certificate.

Comment: @Jeff thanks that was it! i had been trying to get this to work for a couple of days now

Answer (score 3):

I think you are trying to configure your service in a similar way to the following config. There is more information here: [Specify a Service with Two Endpoints Using Different Binding Values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733099.aspx). Also, other than for development, it's probably not a good idea to have both HTTP & HTTPS endpoints to the same service. It kinda defeats the purpose of HTTPS. Hope this helps!

```
<service type="HelloWorld, IndigoConfig, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null">
    <endpoint
        address="http://computer:8080/Hello"
        contract="HelloWorld, IndigoConfig, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
        binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="shortTimeout"
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint
        address="http://computer:8080/Hello"
        contract="HelloWorld, IndigoConfig, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
        binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="Secure"
     </endpoint>
</service>
<bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding 
        name="shortTimeout"
        timeout="00:00:00:01" 
     />
     <basicHttpBinding 
        name="Secure">
        <Security mode="Transport" />
     </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Comment: that looks like a typo in the MSDN. Shouldn't the second basicHttpBinding be closed AFTER the  Security mode="Transport" ?

also interesting that the secure address starts with http, not https.

Answer (score 1):

In my case i am setting security mode to "TransportCredentialOnly" instead of "Transport" in binding. Changing it resolved the issue

```
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="webHttpSecure">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" ></transport>
      </security>
      </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at your base address and your endpoint address (can't see it in your sample code). Most likely you missed a colon or some other typo, e.g. `https//` instead of `https://`

Answer (score 0):

I was using webHttpBinding and forgot to dicate the security mode of "Transport" on the binding configuration which caused the error:

```
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="MyWCFServiceEndpoint">
      <security mode="Transport" />
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
```

Adding this in configuration fixed the problem.