# WCF Security and config help - base address for https not found

Tags: c#, wcf, configuration, wcf-binding, wcf-security

I'm getting this error in my event log for a Windows hosted service.

> Service cannot be started.
>   System.InvalidOperationException:
>   Could not find a base address that
>   matches scheme https for the endpoint
>   with binding BasicHttpBinding.
>   Registered base address schemes are
>   [http].

This service has always worked until recently we wanted to add some security features. Here is my `basicHttpBinding` node and my service node.

```
<basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" transferMode="Buffered" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="52428800" maxBufferSize="65536000" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536000">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="1819200" maxArrayLength="1638400" maxBytesPerRead="1409600" maxNameTableCharCount="1638400" />
        <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential" >
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
        </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="CKISServiceBehavior" name="tcore.CKWcfService.CKISService">
     <endpoint address="CKISService" 
               binding="basicHttpBinding" 
               bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding" 
               bindingNamespace="http://ws.jcore.com" 
               contract="jcore.Common.ICKISService" />
     <endpoint address="mex" 
               binding="mexHttpsBinding" 
               contract="IMetadataExchange" />
     <host>
        <baseAddresses>
           <add baseAddress="https://localhost:9303" />
        </baseAddresses>
     </host>
 </service>
 <behavior name="CKISServiceBehavior">
     <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="300" maxConcurrentSessions="300" maxConcurrentInstances="400" />
     <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
     <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
 </behavior>
```

Any idea what's going on here? My service will no longer start and it's telling me my base addresses aren't set up correctly. How can I remedy this?

Comment: I also did a search and found an issue that was also similar to one I ran into.  Are you running this service behind a load balancer?  If so, is the LB passing the request to the service as HTTPS or HTTP?  Mine was passing it as HTTP.  Here's a similar q&a from SO:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363285/https-with-wcf-error-could-not-find-base-address-that-matches-scheme-https

Answer (score 0):

I get this problem sometimes when Require SSL is enabled in IIS. I think you may need to configure your ssl host headers using command line.

http://www.hosting.com/support/iis7/configure-ssl-host-headers-in-iis7